# Blockquote CSS styling

Tags: bug, design, markdown-rendering

The styling of blockquotes is somewhat sub-optimal

> This is blockquoted

As you can see, there is some extra space at the bottom of the block quote. The reason is this:

```
blockquote {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px 1px;
}

p {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

The margin-bottom of `1em` is inconsistent with the blockquote's padding of `10px`. Code blocks don't have that problem. Top and bottom padding are the same. The following style might help, but I cannot assess whether it would break something else

```
blockquote p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Use [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), or whatever equivalent for non-Firefox browsers,  to adjust to your taste.  I like the current look.

Comment: I don't think this was intentional...

Comment: When changing, I above all would like some line [to indicate nested blockquotes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kUWuB.png). I think Stack Overflow might be one of the few SE sites [to not have that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zCgl2.png)?