# Heading css styles need bigger margin-top or smaller margin-bottom

Tags: bug, design

The margins for headings make my inner child cry.

---

Here's some text

## Heading 1

The gap to this text is more than the text before it

### Heading 2

Here too!

---

Here's an image explaining it with visual helpers:

[image: Visual Assistance Image]

So the request is simple; fix the css for headings and give us nicer layout! Otherwise kittens will die (or some other inappropriate Internet meme).

Comment: This is related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98413/blockquote-css-styling. The bottom margin of some HTML elements is somewhat ambiguous...

Comment: Who says margins above and below have to be even?  When was that rule introduced?  Also, [does this make you angry?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1cGPN.png)

Comment: The margins don't have to be even, but it sure looks weird, since the heading is visually "attached" to the preceding paragraph, rather than the following. If at all, the margin at the top should be smaller than the bottom one. @won

Comment: @Won't: I didn't say even.  Even or greater would be better.  The heading should be bunched with the text below it, not the text above it.  You're not being constructive.

Comment: Also, doing a bit of research about "vertical rhythm" [leads you](http://webtypography.net/Rhythm_and_Proportion/Vertical_Motion/2.2.2/) to [a couple of resources](http://www.thesheep.co.uk/2009/01/14/css-typography-setting-a-vertical-rhythm/) that clearly show [how it should be done](http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm). The spacing should at least be equal.

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin: Correct!  I was trying to be humorous.  Oh, the failure...