# White Space after Header too Big

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I think the white space, after the header markup, is way too large. Answers look more large than they appear to be. On Web Applications, the white space is left or minimized.

See following two screenshots of some answers I've given and the effect it has:

### Web Applications

[image]

### Stack Overflow

[image]

Comment: Related: [Can we balance the whitespace above/below headings?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82281) and [Heading css styles need bigger margin-top or smaller margin-bottom](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105912)

Comment: @CodyGray So, this is not a bug but should be tagged as a feature-request. Why does it take so long (two years) to find consensus? This is clearly an improvement !!

Comment: No idea. I support either or both requests. I have a layout/formatting gripe of my own that has been pretty well ignored: [The leading for lists is too wide and/or is not adjustable on SE 2.0 sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130484)